# C++ CButton showing only bitmap icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio, button, bitmap, mfc

I'm using C++ on Visual Studio 2012 update 4, and I have a Dialog where I want to display a button showing a bitmap (.bmp file), without borders [image: help icon]

I have extended `CButton` to add my tooltip, and so on.

Using the Resource View to open the Dialog `.rc` file, I set the button Property `Bitmap` to `true`. Then, from the Dialog `OnInitDialog` function, I used this code to set the bitmap, identified as `IDB_HELP`

```
myButton.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_HELP), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
```

But it displays this [image: ugly button] and I don't want that half-border.

I tried making it `Flat` and `Transparent` in the Resource View, but it only gets uglier.

Then I tried to only draw the image by setting `Owner Draw` to `true` and then redefining `DrawItem` in my button class, but I can't quite figure that out either.

Any easy way to make an icon-only button?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use owner draw button or custom draw. Below is a simple example, it uses icon instead of bitmap (it's easier to assign transparent background for it)

```
class CMyButton:public CButton
{
    void OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        CRect rc = dc.m_ps.rcPaint;
        dc.FillSolidRect(&rc, GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE));
        BOOL offset = (BST_PUSHED & GetState()) ? 1 : 0;
        int w = 24;
        int h = 24;
        HICON hicon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ICON),
                    IMAGE_ICON, w, h, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        DrawIconEx(dc, offset, offset, hicon, w, h, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL);
        DestroyIcon(hicon);
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, CButton)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Usage:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    static CMyButton bn;
    bn.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1, this);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Don't I also have to redefine DrawItem when the button is Owner Drawn? I've never redefined OnPaint. Could you please elaborate a little bit more about what's going on in the code? Thanks.

Comment: You must override `DrawItem` if button has `BS_OWNERDRAW` flag, and you won't need `OnPaint`. `DrawItem` is more important for controls such as ListBox, because `DrawItem` can paint each list item individually. Also `DrawItem` can paint the button from button's owner, it won't need a separate button class. `OnPaint` method is more useful if you want to do default drawing and do additional drawings on top of that. In this example both methods are similar.

Comment: Thanks. I want to remove the button borders. Is this painting over the old borders? I'm using a 16x16 bitmap, but I can use a similar .ico

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT need to do your own icon painting algorithm if you use a `CMFCButton` and you are a comfortable using an ICO file instead of a BMP. Although you can directly say in your resources file a button is of this type, I do not recommend it, because it adds an unmaintainable hexadecimal piece of text on the rc file. And if you use several rc files, one for each language, it's really devilish!

So lets go. In your form class, declare a member

```
CMFCButton m_button1;
```

The `DoDataExchange` should look like:

```
void MyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    __super::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON1, m_button1);

    // ...
}
```

Then the `OnInitDialog` should be something like:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    if(!__super::OnInitDialog())
         return FALSE;

    m_button1.m_nFlatStyle= CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS;
    m_button1.SetIcon(IDI_HELP);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Was CMFCButton available in Visual Studio 2012 though?

Comment: Yes, I used it even in VS 2010. And even 2008 had it in its Feature Pack. Perhaps you may be missing an `#include` directive.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and use CMFCButton myself. I was just curious. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: I see this class also supports tooltips and custom cursors. Very nice. Will it mess up the visual editor if I make my custom button inherit from CMFCButton instead of from CButton?

Comment: @Agostino: No. I can state I have several classes derived from it. Cursors and tooltips also work nice (I had only one case where tooltips didn't work right, but making a derived class and tweaking a little bit solve the situation)

Answer (score 0):

Use CMFCbutton and set the border style to BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS;

Use a .ico instead of png for pictures.

**Also points to note**:

1. Load the library or exe which has the icon.
2. Pass the dll/exe loaded handle to loadicon.
3. Use MFC button handle to set the icon with property set as Noborder.

**Example code**:

```
m_HResdll = LoadLibrary("C:\\Repos\\iFIX\\SCADABin\\en\\UAAClientConfigurationRes.dll");
//m_hTrustIcon = LoadIcon(m_HResdll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
m_hTrustIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(m_HResdll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2),1,18,22, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
unsigned int  err = GetLastError();
m_btnTrustIcon.SetIcon(m_hTrustIcon);
this->m_btnTrustIcon.EnableWindow(true);
```